# Inserting a formula whose parameter location varies depending on the table

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to write a macro that inserts a formula into multiple lists in the same column. The tricky part is that these lists (all on the same sheet) have the parameters I want to use in this function in varying column locations.

For Example, I want to add a remainder formula to column K; the two columns that I am taking the remainder of, say, the headers "quantity and "quantity sent" can be in varying columns for different lists within the sheet.

How would I go about creating this formula in each of the tables, and have the variables correspond to wherever "quantity" and "quantity sent" are?

Sample data:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/34SmX.jpg

Code:

Comment: You can use Find/Match to locate the header positions and create the formula using that information.

Comment: but if I have multiple lists on a single sheet, how would I know the find/match located the proper heading? Each heading occurs on the sheet multiple times and in different columns, so how could I know that if found the instance of that header that corresponds with that list?

Comment: You'd have to construct your code to take that into account. Think about the steps you'd take to do it *manually* then try to put that process into code.  Are your lists/tables actual tables/listobjects (via Insert>>Table) or just plain data blocks?

Comment: I have been trying and find it to get convoluted very fast. And unfortunately, theyre just plain data blocks, which is why I try to refrain from referring to them as tables

Comment: I have been using the macro recorder and have gotten further into my understanding of VBA, but all the way's im thinking of doing this seems ridiculously convoluted and messy. The way i could think of doing it was possibly with case statements, but that gets ugly quick.

Comment: There is no short solution here.  It would help if you included a screenshot of your data, and any code you've come up with so far.

Comment: Whenever I include my larger Macros I get told no one is going to sift through my code and tell me what to do. But, you got it.

Comment: Is this an Excel question, or an Access question? Please remove  either the [access-vba] or the [excel-vba] tag.

Comment: Apologies. I've removed the Access tag